# Setting the icons of a node in TreePanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, extjs4

ExtJS 4:

I've created a treepanel.
I wanted to set my own icons for its node so I used iconCls property for every node. Its working. But when I expand a node, it returns back to its normal 'Open Folder' icon.

```
var treeObject = {
text: "BANK OF AMERICA 1",
cls: "enterprise",
children: [
    {
        text: "core outputs",
        cls: "businessUnit",
        iconCls: 'abc'
    }
],
iconCls: 'abc',
leaf: "false",
expanded: true,
type: "enterprise"
}
treePanel.setRootNode(treeObject);
```

Please suggest something to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to specify your css class like this to prevent override with the default classes of extjs

```
.x-grid-tree-node-expanded .x-tree-icon-parent.abc{
  background: url(abc) x y no-repat !important;
}
```

Comment: I just needed to include !important after url() without even changing the name of my css. Thats it.
Thank you very much.
But please tell me why it was getting overridden only when I expanded the node.

Comment: the extjs code does not check to see if you have given it a custom iconCls before it sets the folder icon on collapse and expand (there are two different images, open and closed, that it uses for display).  It just sets the icon to the defaults when those events fire.

Comment: @PaulSchroeder! Do you mean to say that !important is overriding their css? But here when I expand the node, it sets the default icon; but when I collapse it, it again displays my custom css. I didn't get this.

Comment: They must have the expanded cls as an extra cls definition creating a more specific pathing in css so that it uses that cls instead, but the !important tag overrides all like css properties.  In a way it does override their CSS, but only for that specific property.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Ext Js 4.0.6, you can use `icon` config on `Ext.data.NodeInterface` to set your node icons - just define a field named 'icon' on your model, use it for your treestore...

```
Ext.define('ModelForTreeNodes', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'icon', type: 'string', defaultValue: "Images/nodeicon.png" },
        // other fields
    ],
    // other config options
});
```

Then you can change the icon by simply setting the icon field on the node...and that's it.

```
var node = myTree.getStore().getNodeById(nodeId);
node.set('icon', 'Images/newIcon.png');
```